# Compiler reports "Segmentation fault: 11"

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int noteven=0, n;

    printf("Input numbers, at the end write 0 \n");
    n=1;

    while(n!=0){
        scanf("%d", n);
            if (n%2==1){
                noteven++;
            }
    }
    printf("Not even numbers quantity: %d", noteven);
}
```

The error appears in terminal after inputting number.
Can anyone please explain why this isn't working?

Comment: When in doubt, *carefully* read the documentation for the offending line of code ([**scanf**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) in this case).  The documentation says, *"the function may expect a sequence of additional arguments, each **containing a pointer** to allocated storage"*

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` requires a pointer to `n`:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

what this means is:

1. scan a string from the keyboard
2. interpret it as an integer (that's the `%d`)
3. put it in the *address* of `n` (the `&` in `&n` means "the address of `n`)

without the `&`, what it says is:

1. scan a string from the keyboard
2. interpret it as an integer (that's the `%d`)
3. take the value of `n` (currently uninitialized, so it holds garbage), and use that value as an address in memory, and store the number there.

Basically, you're telling `scanf` to write an integer in some random place in memory.  You're lucky it only ended in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Oh of course.. Noobie mistake, only today tried C coming from C++.
Thanks!

Comment: @user2897997: This works the same in C++.  Why is this different?

Answer (score 2):

scanf needs the address where it can store the value it reads, so use it as follows:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```